# Sphero Windows Sample App?

Tags: sphero-api

Has anyone gotten the Sample BasicDriveApp App working in Windows 8?

https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-Win-SDK

When I build and run the Project I get a message "No Sphero is connected" and when I try to connect the Sphero via Windows 8 Bluetooth it does not work.

Can anyone offer any tips?

Thanks.

John.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed works, I've had some problems with connectivity myself, however.. process I use to restore if all goes awry:

Refresh `Sphero` (return to base for `sleep mode`, wait a few seconds, wake up)
Refresh `Bluetooth` in Windows (off / on) without connecting to `Sphero`

Open your app, wait for it to connect. It'll find `Sphero` and automatically dig in if all goes well.

[Update]
It appears Windows 8.1 doesn't really know what to do with Sphero. It has a hard time reconnecting after the connection is lost, even if you close all instances of the app and toggle through Bluetooth.